# Clojure for trading strategies

Tags: clojure, trading

Is anybody using Clojure for developing automated trading strategies? What is your experience? I am anticipating learning Clojure and wanted to know whether or not I could use it in this context. If there are any resources for using it in this context, please provide a link. I am currently only using Ruby and JavaScript for web development.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I haven't seen any clojure-specific work in this area, though that probably has more to do with clojure being a brand new language than anything else.  Certainly, clojure's quantitative capabilities are growing -- have a look at [incanter](http://incanter.org) if you haven't already.

If it's low-latency/high-speed trading, then I have my doubts as to whether clojure would be appropriate (despite clojure being my favourite language).  C++ really seems to be the best option in this regard.

Comment: Goldman Sachs uses Erlang, it can't be that much faster than Clojure, that is if it is even faster. Yest cpp rules in the HFT world, along with java, i have heard of python being used by some prop shops, but this is rare. I was looking at marketcetera the open source trading platform and their main language is ruby, thats surprising.

Comment: I believe one of the big reasons why Java (and Clojure) can't be used for HFT is that the garbage collector can kick in at any time and cause delays.

Comment: Could we be more specific when talking about HFT, are we talking about sub 15min level or sub 1. I would like to isolate front running, flash orders, kick backs etc.. and not include them in the discussion. I would like to focus on pure alpha generating strategies between 15min and 10min. As no-one has proven that you can make money consistently after transaction costs at a frequency of higher than 15mins unless you are gaming the system as most current HFT systems do. Yes, cost have dropped but this is a whole other discussion.

Comment: @RubyGladiator: I had in mind High Frequency trading, where I'm told that micro-seconds are the correct time scale.  And I agree that it's gaming the system, I don't think that it provides any value to the economy in large.  For anything reasonable, I think clojure can do very well.  (My feeling is that it'll be faster than Erlang, but someone should really benchmark that).

Answer (score 0):

Clojure can be useful due to its:

- Functional programming capabilities
- Fault tolerance